# Conditional multiplication of multiple series with another series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I would like to multiply (in place) values in one column of a DataFrame by values in another column, based on a condition in a third column.  For example:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 33, 56, 79, 2], 'b': [9, 12, 14, 5, 5], 'c': np.arange(5)})
data.loc[data.a > 10, ['a', 'b']] *= data.loc[data.a > 10, 'c']
```

What I would like this to do is multiply the values of both 'a' and 'b' by the corresponding (same row) value in 'c' based on a condition. However, the above code just results in NaN values in the desired range.

The closest workaround I've found has been to do this:

```
data.loc[data.a > 10, ['a', 'b']] = (data.loc[data.a > 10, ['a', 'b']].as_matrix().T * data.loc[data.a > 10, 'c']).T
```

which works, but it seems like there is a better (more Pythonic) way that I'm missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [mul(..., axis=0)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) method:

```
In [122]: mask = data.a > 10

In [125]: data.loc[mask, ['a','b']] = data.loc[mask, ['a','b']].mul(data.loc[mask, 'c'], 0)


In [126]: data
Out[126]:
     a   b  c
0    1   9  0
1   33  12  1
2  112  28  2
3  237  15  3
4    2   5  4
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one alternative to use `Series.where()` to update values conditionally:

```
data[['a', 'b']] = data[['a', 'b']].apply(lambda m: m.where(data.a <= 10, m*data.c))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

use `update`

```
data.update(data.query('a > 10')[['a', 'b']].mul(data.query('a > 10').c, 0))

data
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems NumPy could be an alternative here -

```
arr = data.values
mask = arr[:,0] > 10
arr[mask,:2] *= arr[mask,2,None]
```

We just extracted the `values` as an array, which is a view into the dataframe and that lets us work on the array and the updates would be automatically reflected in the dataframe. Here's a sample run to show the progress -

```
In [507]: data  # Input dataframe
Out[507]: 
    a   b  c
0   1   9  0
1  33  12  1
2  56  14  2
3  79   5  3
4   2   5  4
```

Use proposed codes -

```
In [508]: arr = data.values

In [509]: mask = arr[:,0] > 10

In [510]: arr[mask,:2] *= arr[mask,2,None]
```

Verify results with dataframe -

```
In [511]: data
Out[511]: 
     a   b  c
0    1   9  0
1   33  12  1
2  112  28  2
3  237  15  3
4    2   5  4
```

Let's try to verify through other way that we were indeed working with a view there -

```
In [512]: np.may_share_memory(data,arr)
Out[512]: True
```

Comment: this is not guaranteed that these are in fact a view; they happen to be as you have a single dtype, but even may not be esp if columns err created iteratively

Answer (score 0):

```
# %%
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

data = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 33, 56, 79, 2], 
                     'b': [9, 12, 14, 5, 5], 
                     'c': np.arange(5)})

(data.loc[data.a>10, ['a','b']]\
 .T * data.loc[data.a>10, 'c'])\
 .T.append(data.loc[data.a<=10, ['a','b']])\
 .T.append(data.c).T.sort()
# %%

Out[17]: 
     a   b  c
0    1   9  0
1   33  12  1
2  112  28  2
3  237  15  3
4    2   5  4
```